# Why is this function handle being used in the incorrect context?

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, anonymous-function

I am trying to understand how to pass functions to `varfun`, which I suppose applies to `arrayfun`, `cellfun` etc.

Reading the helpfile, the first argument should be:

> Function, specified as a function handle. You can define the function in a file or as an anonymous function. If func corresponds to more than one function file (that is, if func represents a set of overloaded functions), MATLAB determines which function to call based on the class of the input arguments.

So I try it with the following data:

```
sampleId = [1 1 1 3 3 3]';
entity = [1 2 3 1 4 5]';
dataTable = table(sampleId, entity)
```

And yes:

```
varfun(@mean, dataTable)

ans = 

    mean_sampleId    mean_entity
    _____________    ___________

    2                2.6667
```

Now, my problem occurs when I define my own function anonymously, for example:

```
mymean = @(x){sum(x)/length(x)};
```

**Then an error is thrown**:

```
varfun(@mymean, dataTable)
Error: "mymean" was previously used as a variable, conflicting with its use here as the name of a function or command.
See "How MATLAB Recognizes Command Syntax" in the MATLAB documentation for details.
```

Yet, if I do not use the at symbol, I get:

```
varfun(mymean, dataTable)

ans = 

    Fun_sampleId    Fun_entity
    ____________    __________

    [2]             [2.6667]
```

I feel like I must be using the function handle `@` in the wrong context. Can anyone enlighten me? (Remark, as noted in the comments the display of `ans` is strange because `mymean` returns a cell array. This was an unintentional error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code snippet, `mean` is a [*(named) function*](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html), and `@mean` is a [*function handle*](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html) to that function. You could equivalently use

```
f = @mean;
varfun(f, dataTable)
```

In the second case, when you define

```
mymean = @(x){sum(x)/length(x)};
```

the `@(x){sum(x)/length(x)}`part is an [*anonymous function*](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), and the variable `mymean` is again a *function handle* to that (anonymous) function. So you need to use `varfun(mymean, dataTable)`, not `varfun(@mymean, dataTable)`.

So, the `@` sign is being used [*in two different ways*](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html), although in both cases it produces a function handle:

- Case 1: to create a function handle from a named function. A named function is a function that is defined in its own file.
- Case 2: as part of an anonymous function definition. An anonymous function is defined directly, not in a separate file. The definition constructs an anonymous function and automatically returns a handle to that function.

Comment: And note that this function creates a `cell` due to `{}`, which explains the unexpected output from `table`. This seems unintentional.

Comment: @Luis, If I did want to use `@mymean` as the function handle, would that mean that I should define a function `mymean` somewhere else? e.g. with `function S = mymean(x) ...`

Comment: @Alex, why would you want to do that?:) (Otherwise, yes.)

Comment: @Alex Exactly. That's what happens with `mean`: it's defined in its own file

Comment: @AndrasDeak Not sure which of my comments you are referring to. If you are wondering why `mymean` returns a cell array, that was simply a typo. If you are wondering why I would want to put `mymean` into a separate file so that I can call it via function handles, it's because I am using `eval` to construct the call to `varfun`, and so the notation has to be consistent

Comment: @Alex, I meant the latter, insisting on using `@`. So, is `eval` inevitable? (I guess so, I assume you also only use it if you really really have to.) But this might be too off-topic regarding your question...

Comment: @Alex I concur with Andras: always avoid `eval` if possible

Comment: yes, maybe this is a topic for a separate discussion, but this is how why I am using `eval`. My function `fn(function_name)` expects a function name as it's argument, I then construct a handle by calling `func = eval(['@' func])`. I suppose now that you have told me to avoid it I could just directly pass the function handle in `fn`?

Comment: @Alex From your code it seems that `func` is initially a string. In that case, use `str2func(func)` to get a handle to the function with the name contained in that string

Comment: @Alex, also note that the substitute proposed by Luis will also treat named and anonymous functions on an equal footing (which makes me sad that I can't upvote it), the result will always be a function handle which you can pass to `varfun`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Good point. `str2func('mean')`, `str2func('@(x)mean(x)')` and `str2func('@mean')` all return function handles.